# hibernate findbyid causes update?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I faced with a very strange behavior in my web app with spring 3 and hibernate-core 3.5.1-Final.

For simplicity i provide  my code..

```
if(ripid!=null){ //Parameter
        Appuntamento apDaRip = appuntamentoService.findById(ripid);

        if(apDaRip.getIdpadre()!=null){
            apDaRip.setNota("RIPROGRAMMATO n."+ripid.toString()+"\n"+apDaRip.getNota());
            apDaRip.setIdpadre(apDaRip.getIdpadre());
        }else{              
            apDaRip.setNota("RIPROGRAMMATO n."+ripid.toString()+"\n"+apDaRip.getNota());
            apDaRip.setIdpadre(ripid);
        }
        try{
            apDaRip.setOrarioinizio(null);              
            apDaRip.setDurata(null);
            //apDaRip.setIdappuntamento(null);


        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

        map.put("appuntamento", apDaRip);

    }

    di = datiintranetService.findById(DatiintranetService.PASS_X_INTERVENTI);
    map.put("passinterventi", di.getBoolean());
```

The idea behind is to use some data of an object "Appuntamento" for produce a new one.
So i'm going to change some value and before send the object to my view (jsp) i fetch other data by calling findbyid. This cause an update to the Appuntamento object... Off course i don't want this behavior. Someone can have an explanation of this?

**Edit-1**

Here's the Dao

```
@Transactional
public class DatiintranetService {

    private DatiintranetDAO datiintranetDAO;

    public void setDatiintranetDAO(DatiintranetDAO datiintranetDAO) {
        this.datiintranetDAO = datiintranetDAO;
    }

    public DatiintranetDAO getDatiintranetDAO() {
        return datiintranetDAO;
    }
    public Datiintranet findById(Integer id) {
        return datiintranetDAO.findById(id);
    }
}
```

and For Appuntamento class I provide to you a snapshot

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "appuntamento", schema = "public")
public class Appuntamento implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="appuntamentoID", sequenceName="appuntamento_idappuntamento_seq",allocationSize =1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="appuntamentoID")   
    @Column(name = "idappuntamento", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getIdappuntamento() {
        return this.idappuntamento;
    }
}
```

**Edit-2**
IF i move thoese two row above the if statement no update occur.

```
di = datiintranetService.findById(DatiintranetService.PASS_X_INTERVENTI);
map.put("passinterventi", di.getBoolean());
```

Comment: Please provide the mapping of your class as well.

Comment: Check my edit-1 Thansk a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you query for an entity and change the entity, the default behavior is to persist those changes via an update to the database. This is usually what you want to happen, but obviously not in all cases.

If you want to avoid the update, you need to detach the entity by calling `session.evict(apDaRip)` where `session` is a reference to the hibernate session (see [`Session.evict()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#evict%28java.lang.Object%29)). You probably want to `evict` the entity right after you get it (immediately following the call to `findById`).

Comment: Mhh, thanks for the reply but, if i move the lasts two row above the if clause no persitation occur. So I could be aggree with the detach approch, but there is somethings more obscure in this behavior.